# Spring application.yml value to lower case

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I am currently using spring.application.name as a postfix to create an index in elasticsearch, which wants the index to be lowercase format.

like so

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      elastic:
        host: ${ES_METRICS_HOST}
        # disabled for local profile
        enabled: true
        # The interval at which metrics are sent to Elastic. The default is 1 minute.
        step: 1m
        # The index to store metrics in, defaults to "metrics"
        index: metrics-${spring.application.name}
```

I was wondering if there is any way i can do a toLowerCase on that reference?

Couldn't find it in the documentation

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using your custom **EnvironmentPostProcessor**, I was testing the answer so below is code I wrote.

- Write an CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor for your application, annotate the class with `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` couldn't add with code because of formatting issue

below is class

```
public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "systemProperties";

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String home = "spring.application.name";
        String key = "management.metrics.export.elastic.index";
        String metricsName = "metrics-" + environment.getProperty(home).toLowerCase();
        map.put(key, metricsName);
        addOrReplace(environment.getPropertySources(), map);
    }

    private void addOrReplace(MutablePropertySources propertySources, Map<String, Object> map) {
        MapPropertySource target = null;
        if (propertySources.contains(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME)) {
            PropertySource<?> source = propertySources.get(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME);
            if (source instanceof MapPropertySource) {
                target = (MapPropertySource) source;
                for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                    if (!target.containsProperty(key)) {
                        target.getSource().put(key, map.get(key));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (target == null) {
            target = new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, map);
        }
        if (!propertySources.contains(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME)) {
            propertySources.addLast(target);
        }
    }

}
```

- once you have written your CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor, register it with application
- cretae **spring.factories** file in resoruces/META-INF
- add the entry of your **CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor** (use your
  own package name)

below is entry

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.shailesh.config.CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

That's all